# Render span element with className attribute in contentful rich text with nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, contentful, richtext

[image: contentful sc]

I want to render contentful richText that contains a span with className attribute(eg: `className = 'blue')` in react app so i can apply that class to a certain segment of title text.
How can i achieve that?